How to retrieve Yahoo Finance tickers for stocks, given the companies' name
I'm a student attempting to download time-series data for 27,000 stocks. I initially tried using Factset's API but lack access (as a student, I am able to manually download data, without access to their API). My next approach was to use Factset's tickers and connect to Yahoo Finance's API. However, the tickers differ across providers. Therefore, I'm considering using the companies' names to obtain their corresponding tickers from Yahoo Finance for automated downloading.
Now, my specific queries are:

How can I retrieve stock tickers from Yahoo Finance using companies' names?
Are 27,000 time-series requests too many, risking a block from Yahoo Finance's API?
Are there alternative methods or financial data providers to obtain this data effectively?

Thank you all in advance!

As a student do you have access to WRDS? If so you can just use CRSP

https://stackoverflow.com/q/77926134/15877695
